# Drawing a line between comments and answers

Tags: discussion

There is a clear case when an answer is not a solution.
For answers that ask a different question or that say "I have the same problem" is pretty clear that they should be flagged/deleted.
But I want to get a clear view on what should be an answer or what should be a comment on "edge" cases.
Here are some examples.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/39818/146

> Check console of your browser. It may be javascript error. At product
>   save time ajax is load before save. If ajax is not working proper your
>   product save functionality is stuck

From my point of view this is a grey area. it doesn't just say "check your console", but it doesn't offer an answer either. It may serve as a bump in the right direction, but it could also spawn a few more questions. I have mixed feelings about deleting this. Any opinions?

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/38740/146

> Did you check Configuration -> Design -> HTML Head -> Default Title
>
> Be aware of Store Scope.

In this particular case, based on the comments on the answer, this did not solve the problem, but it looks to me like a semi-valid answer. It does not explain what the problem might be or how this may solve the problem, but it could solve the problem.

I just took 2 random examples I found while reviewing low quality posts. But for sure there are more like these.

Any opinion could help us define a better scope of this website and keep it healthy.

Comment: **BUMP** This question has 4 doubtful answers on it (out of 4 answers): http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121069/cannot-edit-configurable-product-in-magento-admin